# Fall back order of lang-location in java resource bundle

Tags: java

Say, I have pt in the resource bundle, but no pt_BR or pt_PT. Will pt_BR and pt-PT fallback to pt rather than to english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entries missing in `pt_BR` or `pt_PT` will be looked up in the resource bundle with `pt` base name. `pt-PT` won't fallback to anything (if that's not a typo).

See [ResourceBundle.getBundle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29).